# Android: Passing outputstream of top command to the inputstream of grep to achieve piping " | "similar in shells

Tags: java, android, grep, command, piping

I'm essentially trying to accomplish the same result that running the command:

```
"top -n 1 -s cpu | grep -E 'list_of_package_names'"
```

on a machine that supports shell features such as piping ( | ) would return. That being the rows that are returned by the top command that contain the package name filtered by grep. Normally pretty simple stuff with shell features, however to my knowlegde android does not come with a commands shell and access to these command can only be achieved using Runtime:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...);
```

and then getting the inputstream and reading from it.

The problem is that `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...);` does not know how to deal with shell language and the piping of commands. So is there a way to pipe the ouput of the the top command to the input of the grep command to essentially create the same functionality? Or is there a way to run the commands from a script or anything else that can achieve this result?

On a side note, I have been using adb client/server protocol in my shell commands to test the correctness of the syntax for example:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell top -n 1 -s cpu | grep -E '" + shellParams + "'");`

This returns the expected result as the adb shell contains shell features however cannot be used outside of debugging i.e. at runtime.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, this is my first post so please do let me know if I should be structuring my answer at all differently.